# why can not get response in python when i called Soap

Tags: python, xml, soap

can not request successfully when I call soap in Python. Anyone can help with this?
[image: this is what I wrote now]

Comment: Can you give more info (errors, etc.)?

Comment: Post code as text not an image, questions should provide a [Minimum reproducible example](/help/mcve)